# How to programmatically set navigator handles in highstock?

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts

Is there a way I can programmatically set the markers in highstock navigator, even though I want to keep marker to be set to `{ type: "day", count: 1, text: "1d" }` but not display `Zoom 1d`.

Comment: I think I need some demo. To enable markers in navigator, simply enable them in [the options](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series). Second part of the question is unclear for me. It sounds more like setting `reangeSelector`, not `markers` options.

Comment: @PawełFus: I am using both navigator and rangeselector. Purpose of rangeselector for my chart is only to set default navigator markers to 1 day. Will post a demo in some time.

Comment: Ok, I guess we have here problem with namespace ;) Markers for me are small points on the chart, like circle, diamond etc. You probably mean [handles](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.handles). In that case, to set visible range in the navigator, use `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`.

Comment: @PawełFus: Yes, handles is what I mean, can you give me a short example using angularjs, how to determine a days handle?

Comment: I think angular doesn't matter here. Please, create the demo, so I can see how do you prepare/create the chart.

Comment: @PawełFus: Here is a [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ee0wgyzq0aOzZtjrvLOv?p=preview)

Comment: See `chart.events.load` function: http://plnkr.co/edit/bRnV1lyJHmmx7YURTggq?p=preview

Comment: @PawełFus: Great.  :) You can post your answer, so I can mark it solved. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set extremes without `rangeSelector` using `xAxis.setExtremes()` method: http://plnkr.co/edit/bRnV1lyJHmmx7YURTggq?p=preview

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    height: 600,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var max = this.xAxis[0].max,
            range = 24 * 3600 * 1000; // one day

        this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(max - range, max);
      }  
    }
  },
```

Comment: How can I have same hover point color as when point was hover off? for example: for success I have green so on hover also point should be green . [In docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.marker.fillColor) it says to keep it null but then on hover the color changes to default which is blue

Comment: Because you are setting color per point, not per series. In fact, set `marker: { states: { hover: { fillColor: myColor } } }`. See legend items: http://plnkr.co/edit/tX8eRz962dPHSKR2JwKs?p=preview

Comment: Sorry I did not quite understand.. so I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642310/how-can-i-have-same-hover-point-color-in-highcharts)